received UNAVAILABLE during grpc call: Trust anchor for certification not found
i have the following code for grpc:
val port = 9090
val metadata = Metadata()
metadata.put(Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJCTzdIZWwwSkRpc0YxR1JWd21oZmRxanpJZFdLS1VlX3htWEVkTndsNzZ3In0.eyJleHAiOjE3MTUxNTg0NzksImlhdCI6MTcxNTE1NjY3OSwianRpIjoiZDExMTYwZDEtNGYxZS00ZTgxLTg0NDQtMjQwMjZjMzg5ODM1IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRoLnYyLmZyaWRheS5mYXN0ZWsucGgvcmVhbG1zL0Zhc3Rlay1BdXRoIiwic3ViIjoiM2ZkMDJlZTEtZTk5Ni00N2QzLWEwM2QtMGIyYWVhMmM1MjE5IiwidHlwIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwiYXpwIjoiSzI1ODIzNzMwMDAyOSIsInJlYWxtX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJJbWFnZSBQcm9jZXNzaW5nIEFjY291bnQiLCJQYXJ0bmVyIFNlcnZpY2UgQWNjb3VudCJdfSwic2NvcGUiOiIiLCJjbGllbnRIb3N0IjoiMzUuMjI5LjIzMi40NSIsImNsaWVudElkIjoiSzI1ODIzNzMwMDAyOSIsImNsaWVudEFkZHJlc3MiOiIzNS4yMjkuMjMyLjQ1In0.P3uIa7S36cLN3w49yeeyf0Ddd5nibQuE_nzdJzBOQewjIBwqGPTsPHvtsa59Ldnc_enYbjxzURoJ5ho-FeQZwuIEb2iM5yB_UrzPDFgZbsUBwNH3-Efdv1W-7lS-4XLne4BmT-7fP-H6EFjVTD8pDArSeX53O6fXn79VJJaEFYpZ7CGqEc2NoBmi8dhKpzcJ7ii1-kkPm3sSOiNwjDannXTXy8hA-INuAyE_dZu7souHN_IJL6e7yw8ueeo-eXDPwjB9QxAR09aRfFNGkuzgghPzeIsJAeaf8GLRdNDzF4YB6klaCPOM19-FNuD7P3pdLfAKqD-Dxa2jPl8jjODRow")
metadata.put(Metadata.Key.of("txn-mgr-flag", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "false")
        
val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
            .intercept(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(metadata))
            .forAddress("grpc.friday.fastek.ph", port)
            .useTransportSecurity()
            .build()
try {
val client = FastekBeepClient(channel)
client.stmBalance()

then call the rpc method this way..
client.stmBalance(intialRequest)

take note that i needed to add authorization as header as it was needed
Im still getting UNAVAILABLE status but when i tried it on postman it was working..
Stacktrace:
2024-05-08 11:43:44.650 32644-32644 AndroidRuntime         
ph.skybridge.android                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ph.skybridge.android, PID: 32644
io.grpc.StatusException: UNAVAILABLE
    at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:548)
    at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1$1.onClose(ClientCalls.kt:300)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:564)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:72)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:729)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:710)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    Suppressed:
kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
[StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@d8394aa, Dispatchers.Main]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:100)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:218)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:552)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    ... 18 more

note that i also tried this way in documentation: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config

What was the message part of the UNAVAILABLE status? Status codes include an error description that has useful details.

End of stream or IOException

i've edited the question. if you could check it kindly do so please been stucked with this already.

@EricAnderson I've just run into this in a Firestore context. Here's the entire log: "W/Firestore(24961): (25.0.0) [WriteStream]: (ca0c449) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=null, cause=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."
The device was on a wifi connection without internet, which is where it started, and continued after internet was restored.

The message means that the service certificate is not trusted. You might want to include it into your network_security_config.xml or trust globally.

in case anyone of you might encounter this issue. i have solved it by placing my self signed cert (.pem) file inside the res/raw folder and referencing it inside my network_security_config.xml file.
after that i resolved the hostname missing by appending this line in my okhttpchannelbuilder.
.hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier{ _, _ -> true })
val channel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress("domain name", port)
        .intercept(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(metadata))
        .useTransportSecurity()
        .intercept(loggingInterceptor)
        .hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier{ _, _ -> true })
        .build()


You should never disable the hostname verifier, and there is no need to. You can use builder.overrideAuthority() to specify the hostname that is in the certificate. Disabling hostname verification breaks the security of TLS.
